# Cигналы в QT между несколькими окнами

Tags: c++, qt

Не бросайтесь сразу камнями. Читал и форумы, и документацию и уже неделю тыкаюсь, но все стою на месте. Один раз видел пример, как человек создал кнопку, при нажитии которой открывалось окно, он вписывал текст, закрывал его, отрывал другое окно и там был этот текст. Не могу найти эту статью.

Как работать с сигналами в Qt?

Есть главное окно (`MainWindow`). В главном онке есть

```
public slots: 
void slot_name(QString str);
```

Я создал еще один клас (`Class_2`), обьявил его в файле h по указателю, в конструкторе главного окна

```
temp = new Class_2;
```

Во втором класе, через графический редактор, впендюрил `QLineEdit`.
Создал сигнал

```
signals:
void login(QString &str);
```

Так же создал создал через графический редактор слот

```
public slots:
void login_slot_textChanged(const QString &arg1);
```

В итоге что я хочу и что я получаю. 
В главном окне есть кнопка, при нажатие на которую открывается второе окно через

```
temp->show();
```

В котором я ввожу имя и хочу что бы это имя сохранилось в переменной `QString` из первого окна. По инструкции это можно сделать используя `connect`.
По мануалу и форумам делается так

```
connecnt(ОБЬЕКТ_ИЗДАВАЕМЫЙ_СИГНАЛ, УКАЗЫВАЕМ_ЧТО_ЭТО_СИГНАЛ(ИМЯ_СИГНАЛА), ОБЬЕКТ_ПОЛУЧАЮЩИЙ_СИГНАЛ, УКАЗЫВАЕМ_ЧТО_СИГНАЛ_ПОЛУЧАЕТ_СЛОТ(ИМЯ_СЛОТА));
```

и у меня получается

```
connect(tmp, SIGNAL(login(QString &str)), this, SLOT(slot_name(QString str)));
```

Но ничего не происходит. Как работать с сингалами в одном окне, я разобрался, а вот как с ними работать используя несколько обьектов, не могу догать.

Только прошу вас, не посылайте опять меня на [Документация QT](https://doc.qt.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я извиняюсь, что немного не следовал вашему коду, но мне немного сложно уловить в нем суть.

---

Создаем в другом классе сигнал, который будет означать, что текст в `QLineEdit` изменился

```
connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, SECOND_CLASS, &SECOND_CLASS_NAME::textIsChanged);
```

Когда текст в `ui->lineEdit` изменится будет вызван сигнал `textIsChanged`.

---

В первом классе надо написать слот, который будет обрабатывать сигнал из второго класса `textIsChanged`.
Создаем приватный слот в первом классе:

```
private slots:
    void textIsChangedSlot(QString text)
```

И в cpp файле напишем его:

```
void FIRST_CLASS::textIsChangedSlot(QString text)
{
    qDebug() << text;
}
```

Он просто будет выводить один свой аргумент `text` в консоль.
Не забываем добавить `connect` в первом классе для сигнала из второго класса и слота первого:

```
connect(SECOND_CLASS, &SECOND_CLASS_NAME::textIsChanged, this, &FIRST_CLASS_NAME::textIsChangedSlot);
```

Comment: Вроде все так просто но не для меня)) во втором класе у меня есть сигнал который отправляет QString (void send_name(QString str)), так же есть функция, котрая должна отправлять сигнал при каждом изменении текста сделаная через графический редактор (void Class_2::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    ui->label->setText(arg1);
    emit send_name(arg1);
}) в главном огке есть слот                                                                             void MainWindow::name(QString str)
{
    user_name = str;
    ui->statusbar->showMessage(user_name);
}

Comment: но когда я делаю коннект по вашему примеру, жалуется на то что tmp не является класом ('tmp' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration )

Comment: @Maksim скиньте на pastebin.com код при котором ошибка

Comment: вот сылка на все 4 файла https://pastebin.com/u/guselnikov в 19 строке mainwindow.cpp он жалуется

Comment: Должно быть на 19 строке `&MainWindow::name`

Comment: и все равно жалуется connect(tmp, &tmp::send_name, this, &MainWindow::name);

Comment: сейчас я скопировал ваш пример из коментария, и все равно не помогло) изменений нет

Comment: ошибка та же???

Comment: да. Я вот думаю, либо я как то неправильно создаю втрой клас, и потом так же неправильно его указываю либо я не знаю)

Comment: `connect(tmp, &Class_2::send_name, this, &MainWindow::name);` должно работать.

Comment: ДАА ура. а можно в двух словах, что я не так сделал? То есть сигналы у класса это как статические методы? И когда я использую коннектор, первым параметром я указываю у какого объекта это будет вызывается?

Comment: @Maksim 1) Нет, но точно не уверен. 2) Да. Первый параметр это объект, в котором нужный сигнал

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за помощь. Буду экспериментировать со своей теорией сигнал == статический метод класса

Comment: @Максим это указатель на метод класса, а первый параметр - указатель на объект этого класса. Дратути. Если бы это был статический метод класса, то у него нет первого скрытого параметра указателя на объект. У не статических методов - есть

Comment: войдите отладчиком в emit и там всё увидите, и большой switch и слоты которые можно вызывать безо всяких коннектов и сигналов

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку не очень понравилось как вы tmp создаете (непонятно как оно компилируется вообще)

```
tmp = new Class_2();
connect(tmp, SIGNAL(send_name(QString str)), this, SLOT(name(QString str)));
```

По connect ваша запись правильная.
В остальном посмотрите вывод отладчика. При некорректных коннектах в отладке должен ругаться

Comment: объясните пожалуйста почему? Я в заголовочном файле, в секции приват создал указатель на объект класса (Class_2  *tmp;)  могу ошибаться в терминологии. А в конструкторе выделил память под эту переменную. В деструкторе их удаляю. Если можно в нескольких словах что я делаю не так и почему. Про конект мне уже помогли. Получается что сигнал что-то типо статической функции но не является ею... сам еще не до конца догнал

Answer (score -1):

Можно передать значение переменной из одного окна в другое с помощью конструктора.
допустим у тебя 2 окна onewindow(отсюда берем) и twowindow(сюда передаем).
У окна twowindow укажи параметры, скопируй их в переменные, и потом спокойно их используй.
пример:

```
class twowindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit twowindow(QString path , QString projectname, QWidget *parent = nullptr);//принимаемые параметры
private:
Ui::CodeEditor ui;
private:
    QString Path;
    QString Projectname;
private slots:
    void OpenSelectedFolder_DoubleClick();
    void GoBack_clicked();
};

в другом окне вызываешь этот класс для открытия окна

void click_button(это метод в onewindow)
{
  twowindow *window=new twowindow("1", "lol");//передаем параметры
}
```

Comment: Вопрос был как изъять значение из второго окна в первое. Ваш пример к qt по большому не имеет ни какого отношения.  Вы в конструкторе указали принимающие параметры и когда создаёте объект, передаюте эти параметры